# ¿ Las conexiones de la BD; Al parecer estan CHOCANDO?

Tags: php, jquery

Tengo el problema que se genera al crear  el include  reciente que se llama ( include("thSelect.php"); ), hace que todo  se ponga griss
vomo en la foto

```
    function body(){
        $varHtml ='<body class="centB">';

            if (isset($_SESSION['administrador'])) {
                if (isset($_GET['index']) ) {
                    $varHtml .='<header>';
                    $varHtml .='
                            <img class="clashImg"src="../fotos/clashofclans_paralax2.jpg">
                            <div id="menu">
                                '.$menu = menu().'
                                <div id="titulo">
                                    <img src="../fotos/clashofclans_logo.png">
                                    <h2>Trueque</h2>
                                </div>
                                '.$notaPortada = notaPortada().'
                            </div>

                        ';
                    $varHtml .='</header>';

                    $varHtml .='<div id="cuerpoUsuario">
                                    <div class="herramientasMnCont">
                                        <div class="herramientasMn centFRH">

                                            <div class="caj1-HMn1 buscarHMn">
                                                <div class="imgBuscarHMn">
                                                    <img src="../css3/fonts_icons/buscar.svg" >
                                                </div>
                                                Buscar Aldeas
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="caj1-HMn1">
                                                <div class="imgBuscarHMn">
                                                    <img src="../css3/fonts_icons/vender.svg" >
                                                </div>
                                                Vender Cuenta
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="caj1-HMn1">
                                                <div class="imgBuscarHMn">
                                                    <img src="../css3/fonts_icons/cuentasEVenta.svg" >
                                                </div>
                                                Tus Cuentas en Venta
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="caj1-HMn1">
                                                <div class="imgBuscarHMn">
                                                    <img src="../css3/fonts_icons/ultimPublicaci.svg" >
                                                </div>
                                                Ultimas Publicaciónes
                                            </div>

                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div id="cont-campoBusq" class="centFRH">

                                        <div id="cont-imgBusq" class="centFRH">
                                            <img src="../css3/fonts_icons/buscarOjo.svg" alt="No aparece">
                                        </div>
                                        <div id="select_ThCont">
                                            <select>
                                                <option>$datos</option>
                                                <option>$datos</option>

                                            ';
                                            include("thSelect.php");*Include que me genera problema*

                        $varHtml .='        </select>
                                        </div>
                                        <div id="campoBusq"></div>

                                        <div id="cont-buscCateg">
                                            Buscar por Categoria
                                        </div>

                                        <div id="categoria">';
                                            include("selectCategJquery.php");*Include creado antes del que genera el problema*

                        $varHtml .='    </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>';//Fin del Cuerpo Usuario
    }else{
                $varHtml = '
                    <header>
                        '.$menu = menu().'
                        <div id="subLogo" class="centFRV">
                            <img src="../fotos/clashofclans_logo.png">
                            <h2>Trueque</h2>

                        </div>
                    </header>
                ';
            }
            echo $varHtml;
}
```

**thSelect.php**

```
<?php
    include('../configuracion/conexion.php'); 
?>


 <?php 
    $consulta = "SELECT idCategoria FROM buscar_categoria";
    $resultado = $conexion->query($consulta) or die("Error de busqueda o conexion");

    while ($datosCateorias=$resultado->fetch_assoc() ) {
        $varHtml .= "<option>". $datosCateorias['idCategoria']."</option>";

    }



    mysqli_free_result($resultado);
    $conexion->close();
?>
```

**Normal: antes del include("thSelect.php");**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
**Despues de poner include("thSelect.php");**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Y qué contiene ese `thSelect.php`? Si incluirlo hace que se bloquee la salida, quiere decir que hay algo ahí que produce un error.

Comment: contiene datos que se encuentra en la base de datos como: h1 h2 h3 h4 h5

Comment: ejecute ese archivo aparte y todo se muestra bien pero al incluirlo en la funcion se pone griss

Comment: Ese php lo incluyes en medio de un `select`. Si en medio del select estás colocando h1, h2, etc. puede que te rompa la estructura de la página. Si puedes editar la pregunta y colocar el contenido de `thSelect.php` sería útil para hallar el origen del problema.

Comment: ya lo modifique

Comment: @Gamez puedes poner en la barra de búsqueda `view-source:`, antes de tu link localhost, por ejemplo: `view-source:localhost...` dentro del HTML que se genera debe indicarte donde hay un problema. Viendo tu código quizás haya un problema con la variable `$varHtml` por no inicializarla.